# Booting issue: ×86/cpu: SGX disabled BIOS

Tags: live-usb, bios, boot-repair, uuid, proc

When I boot up I get this message and can’t log on.

```
[  0.185085] ×86/cpu: SGX disabled BIOS.
```

Gave up waiting for root file system device.

Common problems:

1. Boot args (`cat /proc/cmdline`)
2. Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
3. Missing modules (`cat /proc/modules;` Is /dev)

   ```
   ALERT! UUID-df5bOe 76-28ce-4248-8010-1a01d98f0449 does not exist.
   Dropping to a shell!
   Enter *nel.30 for burst of .39 t-7ul unturn bullt-in shell (ash)
   ```
4. List item

Comment: try "sudo updadte-grub"

Comment: Do I need to do this from a live usb or from the initramfs screen?

Comment: From live usb it says /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of ‘/cow’

Comment: /cow is the live installer (Copy on Write). You cannot update grub on it. Best to see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Sorry that took so long. Here is the pastebon result. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YgknXMSgCy/